# php Load an Image from url with json and display

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get images from URL I am very very new to JavaScript. I appreciate your patience with me.

I'm trying to create a script that allows a user to input a name into a text-area, press submit and an image is displayedon web page based on imei no.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0MBL.png)

{"status":1,"image_list":["011975002649_201020131619.jpeg","011975002649_201020134737.jpeg","011975002649_201027135940.jpeg"]}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files are uploaded on your server, and you want to print images with PHP you can do :

```php
$images = array("image1.jpg", "image2.jpg");

foreach ($images as $image) {
   echo "<img src='/path/to/images/$image' />";
}
```

Edit after discussion:

1. You must perform an XHR to getinfo.php. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest
2. On server's answer then test for success or fail

- if success parse JSON, and loop through the table to create an img element each time you want to display an image. See https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement
- otherwise, handle error

Comment: if have 30 images then?

Comment: It will work since you replace $images array with the array containing your images name.

Comment: when i call this url i got respond 
localhost:200/images/getinfo.php?imei=011975002649

this
{"status":1,"image_list":["011975002649_201020131619.jpeg","011975002649_201020134737.jpeg","011975002649_201027135940.jpeg"]}

Comment: Please, be clearer about what you want to do, how you are currently doing it step by step.

Comment: i want when i call this use just displayed image on webpage

Comment: localhost:200/images/getinfo.php?imei=011975002649

Comment: So you are requesting the page getinfo.php with JS ?

And then you want to show images returned in the array ?

Comment: <?php 
$fileName = $_REQUEST['imei'];
$output_value = array();
$output_value["status"] = 1;

if(is_dir($fileName)){
    $a = scandir($fileName);
    $output_value['image_list'] = array_slice($a, 2);
} else {
    $output_value['image_list'] = array();
}

echo json_encode($output_value);

?>

Comment: Well so you want to render pictures with JS ?

Comment: Okay. You really should update your question to be clearer. Well I edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, To PHP Load an Image from URL and display

```
<?php

$image = 'http://www.google.com/doodle4google/images/d4g_logo_global.jpg';
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$imageData.'">';
?>
```

I hope this code will be useful to you.

Thank you.