# php Load an Image from url by String variable

Tags: php, string, image, url, concatenation

I got this code from [php Load an Image from url with json and display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64814519/php-load-an-image-from-url-with-json-and-display)

```
$image= 'https://www.google.com/doodle4google/images/d4g_logo_global.jpg';
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));

echo '\<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$imageData.'">';
```

This works however when I retrieve a String value from my database in mysql using a for loop, as shown below, and replace the above $image variable with my new $String variable, the following error ensues (I already tried concatenating the ' characters into the String and even loading the completed website and '' characters around it):

> Warning:
> file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/doodle4google/images/d4g_logo_global.jpg'):
> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\boardGame\includes\searchName\search.php on line 19

```
require_once('DB.php');


$name = $_POST ['name'];

$con =new DB();
$data = $con ->searchData($name);
foreach($data as $i) {
    echo $i["image"];
      }
 
 foreach($data as $i) {
   $String=  $i["image"];
 }

     

$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($String));
```

Comment: The warning indicates the URL is wrapped in quotes but it shouldn't be.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I think it is the `http` instead of `https`.

Comment: I think your setup doesnt work external url using file_get_contents...or probably you can look this setting allow_url_open... you may probably use cURL instead.

Comment: Thank you guys! It took both changing the https change and the unwrapping of the URL for it to work!